# Erase elements from vector struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, erase

So I started learning vector and I wanted to erase a element from a struct vector, I have this as struct:

```
typedef struct Carro{
   int id, cc, cv;
   char marca[50], modelo[50];
}car;

typedef struct Condutor{
   vector<car> cars;
   int id;
   int totalC=0;
   char nome[50];
}driver;
```

and this to delete:

```
for(int i=0; i< (*ptr).size(); i++){
    if((*ptr)[i].id == id){
        (*ptr).erase((*ptr).begin +i);
        verif=true;
        break;
    }
    else{
        verif=false;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work as I get this error in the erase line while trying to run it:

```
invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator+'
```

How can I delete an element from vector?

Comment: [OT] Are you coming from C by chance?  You have a couple C'isms in your code that you do not have to do in C++.

Comment: And even in C you can say `ptr->thing`

Comment: begin() is a method?

Comment: That specific error is probably caused by you writing `begin + i` instead of `begin() + i`, but we cannot tell unless you post an MCVE. We don't have a crystal ball and don't know anything about your `ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `ptr` is, this is a bit a of a guess, but you probably want instead of:

```
  (*ptr).erase((*ptr).begin +i);
```

this:

```
 ptr->erase( ptr->begin() +i);
```

begin() is a function - your code tries to treat it as a function pointer.

Comment: Yeah I forgot, ptr comes from main and it's &driver. Your answer is correct i'll give you check, I've been going around for to long in this and all for a simple (). Thanks